# Using ZSH, how can I replace variables from a dictionary

Tags: shell, installation, zsh, package-managers

I'm making a simple `install.zsh` to put in my dotfiles. It's mostly used to install stuff like ruby-gems, npm, pip and so on, and then I install the rest using those package managers. 
But in order to get to that level, I still need to install those package managers using the correct platform-dependent syntax. Not to mention all the stuff that is only available in the platform-dependent package manager.

99% of this is solved using a simple function like this:

```
install(){
  command -v brew && echo "installing $1 using Homebrew" && brew install "$1"
  command -v pkg && echo "installing $1 using pkg" && sudo pkg install "$1"
  command -v apt-get && echo "installing $1 using apt" && sudo apt-get install "$1"
}
```

1 % of the time this won't work due to brew, pkg and apt-get expecting different packagenames. For example, pkg wants dev/ruby and dev/ruby-gems; apt wants ruby-full, and brew just wants ruby.

So I need a subfunction which replaces $1 with the platform-correct package name WITHOUT a huge switch tree consisting of smaller switch trees! I can already do that, and not only do I not want to write it, but I don't want to maintain it when I add new packages... I'd rather have something like a plaintext "database" consisting of rows of four fields like this:

```
'ruby','ruby-full','dev/ruby,dev/ruby-gems',ruby
```

Or something with better syntax, it's not very important. The subfunction is more important.

Of course, if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here, if someone can point me to a wheelwright that would be even better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *99% of this is solved using a simple function*, you probably don't want to create "database" entries for the 99 out of 100 cases where it isn't needed. For the 1 % exceptions, you could e. g. create arrays named **pkgs_***name* (with *name* being the generic name of the "stuff"), which contain three elements, the *different packagenames* for [1] apt, [2] pkg and [3] brew.

```
pkgs_ruby=(ruby-full 'dev/ruby dev/ruby-gems' ruby)
```

Then a function, let's call it `pkgs()`, passed the package manager's index and the stuff's name, could check whether the array **pkgs_***name* exists and if so return the packagename(s) for the index, otherwise just the generic name, like:

```
pkgs()
{
    eval echo \${pkgs_$2\[$1]-$2}
}
```

You'd then just have to modify the `install()` function to take what `pkgs()` returns instead of just `"$1"`:

```
install()
{
  whence brew    && echo "installing $1 using Homebrew" &&      brew    install `pkgs 3 $1`
  whence pkg     && echo "installing $1 using pkg"      && sudo pkg     install `pkgs 2 $1`
  whence apt-get && echo "installing $1 using apt"      && sudo apt-get install `pkgs 1 $1`
}
```

So, `install ruby` would take the information from `$pkgs_ruby` and execute e. g.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

while `install java` without any definitions would execute e. g.

```
sudo apt-get install java
```

Comment: It's certainly a start, and the idea of simply putting the package names in variables hadn't even occured to me... 
I'm currently dog-sitting, so I'm not at home, but I'll have a look week after next to see if I can make this work.

Comment: I tried it, but the pkgs() function, which I renamed getPackage for legibility, doesn't seem to work.
https://gist.github.com/tofagerl/628df7dd07ef47073cf808e85014b600

install ruby gives the following results: 
On mac, 'ruby'
On ubuntu, 'dev/ruby dev/ruby-gems'
On freebsd, 'ruby'

Oh, and whence doesn't work on macs, that's why I use command -v

Comment: Obviously, I could just unpack the variable and use $pkg_ruby_brew, $pkg_ruby_apt and so on... But that is so "brute force" ;)

Comment: @tofagerl: From your question I read you're using `zsh`. Your github script doesn't work because `bash` is used there. The difference here is that array  elements in `zsh` normally are numbered beginning with _1_ in contrast to _0_ in other shells as `bash`, where the first argument of `getPackage()` has to be _0_, _1_ or _2_.

Comment: @tofagerl: You could set `zsh`'s `KSH_ARRAYS` option to force element numbering from zero.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just changed the script to use 0. It is a problem that this script now can't be run in zsh, but I'd rather have it as POSIX-compatible as possible.

Comment: @tofagerl: You could put something like `setopt KSH_ARRAYS >&/dev/null` into the script to make it run with `zsh` as well.